# no bluetooth adapters found with BCM43602 xps15

Tags: 18.04, wireless, bluetooth, dell

I know the xps series doesn't play well with ubuntu by reading about a hundred tutorials on different way to fix the bluetoooth connectivity problem. For some reason Nothing has worked for me. I tried to add the hcd file to no avail. I tried just about everything and im stumped. This is a pretty serious issue because im on my 5th set of speakers, this laptop is notorious for blowing speakers, i was hoping to just connect bluetooth speakers to avoid this problem. If anyone can help be diagnose this issue i would be greatly appreciate it and Please dont delete this thread it hasn't been answered before. Nothing has worked on my device for some reason.

Comment: What does `dmesg | grep -i blue` show? And `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb`

Comment: dmesg | grep -i blue shows nothing

Comment: `2:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [14e4:43ba] (rev 01) Subsystem: Dell BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [1028:0024] Kernel driver in use: brcmfmac Kernel modules: brcmfmac Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1bcf:2b95 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub    `

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information. It is unreadable in comments.